# Fix fiber glass tub or replace

Tags: leak, bathtub, crack, epoxy

I have a fiber glass tub, which has developed cracks and was sealed with epoxy. 6 months ago, the crack reopened and so I re-applied the epoxy. 2 months ago, the crack extended in front of the epoxy and then I reapplied epoxy. So right now, it has 3 applications of epoxy + a fiber glass patch. (see photos here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/etwel.jpg)

Was wondering if this tub still has life, or should I bite the bullet and have it replaced. I was quoted $3,800 + tax for 1. demolition of the tub/surround, 2. Adding a new tub, waste and overflow, 3. A new cement backerboard + waterproofing, and 4. 12" x 12" tiles as the new surround. Wondering if this is reasonable (I live in Seattle). Thanks!

Comment: When you patched it did you drill a hole and use spray foam or insert something to support the bottom of the tub? Have you had a repair by a capable professional?

Comment: No, I did it myself with a kit I got online. Just sanded it, put a piece of fiber glass, and put epoxy on that, which was left to dry for a day.  Do you think this would be fixed once and for all with support for the tub at the bottom?

Comment: I believe the proper support is necessary for the repair to work. Sometime the repair is to put fuse a tray to the bottom of the tub rather than just patch a spot.  It might be time to get an estimate from a competent pro.